# predicting categorical variable by continues variables

Tags: r, glm

I am doing a logistic regression analysis to predict a categorical variable(sex) by more than one continuous variable. However, I encounter some errors and really need someone to help me.

Here I put the simulation data and the codes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(purrr)

data <- data.frame(cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20),
                      shar = rep(c("fr", "bs"), each = 20),
                      sex = rep(c("f", "m"), each = 20),
                      bmi = runif(20, min = 0, max = 30),
                      fbg = runif(20, min = 70, max = 140),
                      AB = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1),
                      Ac = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1),
                      Ad = runif(20, min = 0, max = 3),
                      Ae = runif(20, min = 0, max = 4),
                      Af = runif(20, min = 2, max = 4),
                      Ba = runif(20, min = 2, max = 10),
                      Bb = runif(20, min = 10, max = 40),
                      Bc = runif(20, min = 5, max = 50),
                      BD = runif(20, min = 0.5, max = 1),
                      BF = runif(20, min = 5, max = 10),
                      Ca = runif(20, min = 2, max = 10),
                      Cb = runif(20, min = 10, max = 40),
                      Cc = runif(20, min = 5, max = 50),
                      CD = runif(20, min = 0.5, max = 1),
                      CF = runif(20, min = 5, max = 10))

data1 <- data %>% 
  gather(Fac, value, -cat:-sex) %>% 
  split(.$Fac)  %>% 
  map(~glm(sex ~ value,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data =.) %>%  
        tidy(.) %>% 
        select(estimate, std.error,statistic,p.value) %>% 
        slice(2)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "variables")
```

This was the error

> Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1.

Then, I modified the code as got but still got an error

```
data$gendr <- ifelse(data$sex =="m",1L,0L)
data1 <- data %>% 
  gather(Fac, value, -cat:-sex) %>% 
  split(.$Fac)  %>% 
  map(~glm(gendr ~ value,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data =.) %>%  
        tidy(.) %>% 
        select(estimate, std.error,statistic,p.value) %>% 
        slice(2)) %>%  ## Extracting regression of genes
  bind_rows(.id = "varaibles")
```

The error was

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'gendr' not found

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the reprex package to create the correct code for posting reproducible examples. I just tell you because I wonder what the `´´´` is doing in your code.

Comment: In your first attempt just do `glm(sex == "f" ~ value, etc)`. See this recent [R-Help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-August/468173.html) by William Dunlap, the thread starts [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-August/468157.html).

Comment: I don't know the reason why, but when I run your code it works well (using R3.6.1 here).
In addition to Rui Barradas comment, I get the same results as running it with: `glm(sex == "m" ~ value, etc)`

Comment: @Arault and JBGruber, Thanks for your feedbacks! I will try it with R 3.6.1. However, if I want to take variable **cat**  as a response Considering category D as a reference group, should I model it as you indicate for the sex or it is something different?

Comment: It depends on what you consider as "reference group", if you want to "detect" D as the target, then you should write `glm(cat=="D"~...)` so your output would be the "probability" (sort of) of an individual belonging to the D category. Otherwise if you want to detect **anything but D** you should do `glm(cat!="D"~...)` which would focus on finding non D responses